# Discord.js code isn't working. I should give a the member a role but it says add is undefined

Tags: discord.js

Here is my code:

```
let userlist = [];

let reactedlist = [];

client.on('message', msg=> {
    const filter = () => {
        return true
    };

    const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 86400000 });

    collector.on('collect', (a,reaction) => {
        console.log(reaction.id);
        if(!userlist.includes(reaction.id) && !reactedlist.includes(reaction.id)){
            userlist.push(reaction.id)
        }
        console.log(userlist);
        userlist.forEach(id => {
            const userReactions = msg.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(id));
            try {
                let duo = '';
                for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
                    duo+=reaction.emoji.id;
                }
                if(duo.includes('854754738956664901') && duo.includes('854754766609055764')){
                    userlist.shift();
                    const member = client.users.fetch(id);
                    let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(i => i.id === '854756696965644319')
                    member.roles.add(role);
                    if(!reactedlist.includes(id)){
                    reactedlist += id;
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    });

    collector.on('end', collected => {
        console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
    });



});



client.login('');
```

Comment: `member` is a user object.

Comment: If the answer works for you, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users cannot have roles added to them.

To get the GuildMember, you should be going into the guild and fetching from the GuildMemberManager.

```js
const member = await msg.guild.members.fetch(id);
member.roles.add(role);
```

Comment: You can also use `<guild>.member(user)`